# Understanding intermediate values - SHA2 - 512

Tags: hash, sha-512

I am trying to understand SHA2 - 512 algorithm, so I am [following this document](https://csrc.nist.gov/CSRC/media/Projects/Cryptographic-Standards-and-Guidelines/documents/examples/SHA512.pdf) which has the intermediate values for the string "abc". At `t=0`, the values for `f`, `h` and `g` are straightforward. But I am not getting the same value for `e`, which suggests that I am doing something wrong when I am computing $T_1 = h + \Sigma_1(e) + \text{Ch}(e,f,g) + K_i + W_i$. I am almost sure that I have implemented $\text{Ch( )}$ and $\Sigma_1 ( )$ correctly. I guess my issue might be with the addition over $\pmod {2^{64}}$. I understand each term in summation of $T_1$ is a 64-bit number. So I assume we can convert these numbers to integers and add them up over $\pmod {2^{64}}$. Now the resulting number may not be 64-bit long in binary. Do we add $0$'s in front of behind the binary representation to make it 64-bit long?

I am not sure if this is helpful, but here are a few values I am getting in binary for `t=0` (for now I am adding zeros to the left of the most significant bit):

```
#Sigma_1(e)
0101000100001110010100100111111110101101111001101000001011010001

#Ch(e,f,g)
0001111110000101110010011000110001111011001001110011110100111011

#T_1
0110100101100101001100111001100011001110110101111110100010100000

#e <- T_1 + d
0000111010110101001010001101001100101101111101010001111110010001
```

whereas according to the document, `e` in binary is `1100001111010100111010111111110101001000011001010000111111111010`.

If you can provide a resource that includes the intermediate values for these other functions, I hope I can figure it out. Otherwise, it would be much appreciated if you could give a detailed explanation for how to get the correct value. Please let me know if you would like me to include more information.

Comment: Do you mean SHA3-512 or SHA2-512 (also known as SHA512)?  The document you cited and the particulars of your question are for SHA2-512.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I assumed SHA-512 means SHA3-512, so I was wrong about it. I will edit the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you really mean SHA2-512:

> #Sigma_1(e)
> 0101000100001110010100100111111110101101111001101000001011010001

The value of 'Sigma_1' is incorrect; I just instrumented a known-good implementation and got for the first round:

$$sigma1 = 9427e33bb5c9dbca$$

Maybe you had the $ROTR$ operations as shifts, not rotates...

Now, as for your musings:

> I understand each term in summation of $T1$ is a 64-bit number. So I assume we can convert these numbers to integers and add them up over $\pmod {2^{64}}$. Now the resulting number may not be 64-bit long in binary.

Actually, the most natural way to represent values within SHA-512 would be as always using 64 bits; these bits are interpreted as a value within the range $[0, 2^{64}-1]$; often, the msbit may happen to be zero; we still treat it as a 64 bit value (and so never need to add 0's at the beginning or the end - the values are always the correct length).

Yes, this is not the way we count bits in RSA - SHA-512 is not RSA.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, `d` in hex is `A54FF53A5F1D36F1`, which in binary is `1010010101001111111101010011101001011111000111010011011011110001`. So the 4 lsbits are `0001`. The other point is that the summation is not XOR. According to the description, it is over `mod 2^64`.

Comment: I misread the test vector; you are correct in the initial value of $d$; it's the value of $T1$ that's wrong (and BTW, I am quite aware that addition is $\bmod 2^{64}$...)

Comment: Thank you for computing sigma_1. Now am I getting the same value. The issue was when I converted hex to int to binary in Python, I only got as many bits that was necessary for that integer value, not 64-bits necessarily. I added 0's to the left of the binary representation, and it works fine right now!